# Setting formula for maxBounds in Leaflet not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to use a formula to compute the maxBounds that will be set for the map, but I cannot get it to work. Has it something to do with the numbers not recognized as integers (since I tried using numbers as the latitude and longitude and it would work).

```
<div id='latitude'>17.5965</div>
<div id='longitude'>120.6179</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML;
var lon = document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML;

var minLat = lat - 0.3; //subtract 0.3
var minLon = lon - 0.3; //subtract 0.3
var maxLat = lat + 0.3; //add 0.3
var maxLon = lon + 0.3; //add 0.3

var bounds = [[minLat,  minLon], [maxLat, maxLon]];

L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", opacity:0, weight: 0}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds, {reset: true}).setMaxBounds(bounds);
map.setView([lat, lon], 13);
```

Comment: Probably [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: Previously tried using parseInt which did not solve it, but this works. Thank you very much.